# silverlight makes differences between localhost and machinename?

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight-4.0, iis-7.5

I deployed a Silverlight webapplication to IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Express 2008 R2. If I connect to the application via localhost:port or ip:port I can logon.

When I visit the webapplication through it's machinename (srv_dev:port), I could not login.

If I debug the xap the following error occurs in the SilverlightApplication\Service References\Service ReferencesMembership\Reference.cs

```
public SilverlightApplication.ServiceReferenceMembership.User EndGetUserByUserName(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            SilverlightApplication.ServiceReferenceMembership.User _result = ((SilverlightApplication.ServiceReferenceMembership.User)(base.EndInvoke("GetUserByUserName", _args, result)));
            return _result;
        }
```

Communication Exception - remote server returns Error: NotFound.

The applications uses a custom membership provider with asp.net membership tables.

Do I have to configure something? Site bindings are:

type     hostname port ip-adress bindinginformations

http     none     3130 *         none

net.pipe none     none none      localhost

net.msmq none     none none      localhost

Why are there differences between localhost / machinename for Silverlight?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That's Silverlight's version of a `404 Not Found` response.

Usually when I see that error I always find out I forgot to fix my service reference's endpoint address, which keeps pointing to localhost instead of the remote address of the service.